# What's the Integer equivalent to Array.map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So if I wanted to do something like

```
var numberOfRows = 5;
numberOfRows.map(index => {
    return(<tr></tr>)
})
```

I know I can create an empty list but that seems definitely wrong. I feel like there's probably a function for this I just don't know it.

Comment: You're looking for a `for` loop.

Comment: But if I want to return in a for loop that will return from the function

Comment: Yes, that is an accurate statement of what `return` does, I'm not sure what that has to do with anything.

Comment: You've not quite sufficiently described the behavior you would expect that code to have. Mapping is a mathematical concept that doesn't make sense for integers, but if you describe what you want we can do our best to help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to achieve this:

```
Array(numberOfRows).fill().map(index => {
    return(<tr></tr>)
})
```

it will render the same number of `<tr>` tags as specified in `numberOfRows` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array.from` callback, which acts like `map`:

```
Array.from(Array(numberOfRows), _ => {
    return(<tr></tr>)
})
```

Or, to really avoid the creation of an array before the mapping completes:

```
const length = 5;
Array.from({length}, _ => {
    return(<tr></tr>)
})
```

Here the name is chosen to be `length` so the short ES6 notation can be used for the object literal. Otherwise it would be `{ length: numberOfRows }`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Andrzej's answer, you can also do:

```
[...Array(numberOfRows)].map(index => {
  return(<tr></tr>)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

```
[...Array(n).keys()]
```

So you can use the `index` in a high order fashion within the map:

```
[...Array(n).keys()].map(index => {
  // do something with the index value
  return(<tr></tr>)
})
```

For example:

```
[...Array(10).keys()]
> Array [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]

[...Array(10).keys()].map(index => index + 1)
> Array [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

Comment: another fun magical way to count: `[...Array(10)].map( Function.call.bind(Number) )`